# Testing nested CanCan abilities with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, cancan

I spent a bit of time digging through CanCan to get nested resources working.  It works as expected in the browser, but I can't get the related ability spec to pass.  I'm guessing it has something to do with how CanCan handles nested routes.  Any suggestions on how to properly test the failing abilities (marked below)?  Thanks.

```
  describe "Network" do
    let(:network) { Network.new }

    describe "#read" do
      it "allows a user that meets the can_read? requirements" do
        NetworkManagementPolicy.stub_chain(:new, :can_read?).and_return(true)
        ability_for(user).should be_able_to(:read, network)
      end

      it "denies a user that does not meet the can_read? requirements" do
        NetworkManagementPolicy.stub_chain(:new, :can_read?).and_return(false)
        ability_for(user).should_not be_able_to(:read, network)
      end

      describe "Affiliation" do
        let(:affiliation) { Affiliation.new }

        describe "#manage" do
          it "allows a user that meets the can_modify? requirements" do
            # NOTE: Not sure why this is failing; Something to do with how
            # CanCan handles nested resources?
            # 
            # NetworkManagementPolicy.stub_chain(:new, :can_modify?).and_return(true)
            # ability_for(user).should be_able_to(:manage, affiliation)
          end

          it "denies a user that does not meet the can_modify? requirements" do
            NetworkManagementPolicy.stub_chain(:new, :can_modify?).and_return(false)
            ability_for(user).should_not be_able_to(:manage, affiliation)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

The ability class defines the following related to reading networks and managing affiliations.  The NetworkManagementPolicy class returns true/false based on certain criteria and works as expected.  Even when removing the calls to this class and hard returning true/false, I can't get the abilities specs to pass.

```
  can :read, Network do |network|
    can :manage, Affiliation do |affiliation|
      NetworkManagementPolicy.new(network).can_modify?(current_user)
    end

    NetworkManagementPolicy.new(network).can_read?(current_user)
  end
```

Comment: Are you sure you can invoke the second `can` inside a block?  I don't see any such examples on the [Defining Abilities with Blocks](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks) wiki page.  Remember, the block isn't evaluated until the permission is checked.

Answer (score 1):

We need more specifics about your models and the "can_read?" conditions to properly answer this question. I am not sure how your Affiliation model relates to the NetworkManagementPolicy or Network.

However, given that a network has_many network_management_polices and that each affiliation is attached to a user and network with standard rails conventions this should get you moving.

```
class NetworkManagementPolicyController < ApplicationController
    load_and_authorize_resource :network
    load_and_authorize_resource :network_management_policy, through: :network
end

can :manage, NetworkManagementPolicy, network: { affiliations: { user_id: current_user.id} }
```